# HighCharts: reordering yAxis categories on the fly won't draw properly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a function that will allow me to add a series dynamically to my highchart. (I'm adding series's with their names as integer values and have them sorted in ascending order).

```
$('#addSeries').on('click', function() {
    //first check if value is already a series
    var seriesid = document.getElementById('txtValue').value;
    getSeriesIDIndex(seriesid, function(idindex) {
        //if it doesnt exist, add it to chart
        if (idindex == -1) {
            categories.push(parseInt(seriesid));
            categories = categories.sort(sortNumber);
            chart.yAxis[0].setCategories(categories, false);
            getCategoryIndex(parseInt(seriesid), function(cindex) {
                chart.addSeries({name: seriesid,  data: [{x: currentDate.getTime(), y: cindex}]}, false);

                for (i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
                    (function(i) {
                        getCategoryIndex(chart.series[i].name, function(cindex) {
                            for (y = 0; y < chart.series[i].data.length; y++) {
                                chart.series[i].data[y].y = cindex;
                                chart.redraw();
                            }
                        });
                    })(i);
                }

                chart.redraw();
            });
        }
    });
```

First add a series "123", then "44" and it will not display properly... but then add another series "555" and it gets redrawn properly. The category indeces for these would be 0 for 44, 1 for 123, and 2 for 555 (because I want to keep the series categories in ascending order). So it seems that when adding a series category of lesser value than the other categories, it won't redraw correctly

I've also created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5L59r1qt/17/

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/qner9hwc/1/

```
             getCategoryIndex(parseInt(seriesid), function (cindex) {
                chart.addSeries({
                    name: seriesid,
                    data: [{
                        x: currentDate.getTime(),
                        y: cindex
                    }]
                }, false);
                for (i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
                    var cur_series = chart.series[i];
                    var cur_cindex;
                    getCategoryIndex(chart.series[i].name, function (cindex) {
                        cur_cindex = cindex;
                    });
                    for (var z = 0; z < cur_series.data.length; z++) {
                        if (cur_series.data[z].y >= cindex && cur_series.name !== seriesid) {
                            console.log('change!' + cur_series.data[z].y);
                            cur_series.data[z].y = cur_cindex;
                        }
                    }
                }
                console.log(chart.yAxis[0].categories);
                chart.redraw();
            });
```

The y values now get changed accordingly;

However the yaxis is a little bit too high right now. Maybe the others can figure out why that is the case. (look at the tooltip on state hover, the values are correct now)

Comment: looks good thanks! it still has issue where if you add value that is not the highest value it doesnt display. just try adding 123 first then add 25 as an example to see what I mean.

Comment: Yes as stated above, this seems to be an issue with the y axis, not with the values themselves. maybe some other folks have ideas on that?

Comment: when you add a multitude of series, then you will see that the highest values also get displayed. still the y axis is not fitting